# How to publish to rtmp services such as youtube/facebook with agora web sdk

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have created youtube/facebook live events, account on agora and tried with agora demo on web demo:

https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-websdk-api-example-4.x/pushStreamToCDN/index.html

I am getting Unexpected_Response when I can client.startLiveStreaming(youtube_rtmp_url, false);
I also tried to change client to use 'h264' codec but the same failure.

Probably I am using youtube live stream url wrong. I tried multiple combinations of rtmp url:

rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2

rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/secret_stream_key

rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?custom_variable_name=secret_stream_key

But No success so far. Am I missing something?

Exact Error message on console:
`live streaming error: AgoraRTCError UNEXPECTED_RESPONSE: live streaming app center error, code: 400, reason: invalid_appid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing this issue because you haven't enabled RTMP in your console. Please refer this [link](https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/cdn_streaming_web?platform=Web#prerequisites).

Also make sure you are publishing to livetranscoding after the channel is joined. Use the relevant callbacks to make sure this is happening.

**NOTE:** You need to add / after the main URL of rtmp.

Example: `rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live1/jmhw-rgv0-uem7-6411-195h`